# Replicating a join in mongodb / react

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have 2 schemas simplified for brevity.

```
Schema.Adviser = new SimpleSchema({
  "firstname": {
    type: String
  }
});

Schema.Account = new SimpleSchema({
  "adviserId": {
    type: Object
  },
  "period": {
    type: Date
  }
});
```

I need to represent data in a table similar to this:

firstname | period

Both fields should be editable. This will require the datasets to either merge or run parallel? Not sure how that would work.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `reywood:publish-composite` [package](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) for publishing the data.  For writing data, as long as you have the adviser _id you'll just be doing two writes.

```
// Server publish-composite example
Meteor.publishComposite('advisersAccounts', {
    find: function() {
        return Advisers.find({}, {});
    },
    children: [
        {
            find: function(adviser) {
                return Accounts.find(
                    { adviserId: adviser._id },
                    { limit: 1 });
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

You'll be able to use template helpers to return the appropriate data client-side.  Something like this:

```
advisers() {
    return Advisers.find();
},
account() {
    return Accounts.findOne({adviserId: this.accountId});
}
```

In Template:

```
{{#each advisers}}
    {{account.period}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hi Steven

Is it necessary for it to be in that order? Advisers being children of Accounts? In my case the reverse is true. In which case a template helper like should work I think?

orderGetter: function() {
      return Account.find({adviserId: this._id});
    }

Comment: Nope, it's not necessary to be in that order.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Finally, how would I access in my template in an {{#each adviser}} loop the account information. For example, the account.period? I've created a template helper as above but it returns no data, yet through a mongo query it returns fine?

Comment: Thank you very much. It's still not working but it must be something I'm doing wrong. Will keep trying. Thanks again

Comment: I think it's because I have a body.helper that returns Advisers.find({}) and therefore has no concept of accounts. When using this package do you need to replace that with something that joins the schemas?

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. It was a simple typo calling my collection account instead of accounts. Painful how long I've wasted on that, but all working now. Thank you.